# PROBLEMA CON IMPORTAR DATOS EN SAS DESDE TXT

Tags: sas

Estoy importando un archivo .txt de casi 10 millones de registros en SAS que esta delimitado por tabuladores, pero cuando lo importo veo que hay unos datos que quedan truncados porque incluyen un tabulador en su celda.

Por ejemplo, tengo la variables dirección y uno de sus registros tiene la siguiente información
"Carrera 14 # 12 (tab)  Manzana 3"
cuando lo importo en sas me sale solo "Carrera 14 # 12" porque asume que lo otro hace parte de la siguiente variable

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: ¿Te sería viable editar el .txt o delimitarlo por posiciones de texto fijas?

Comment: Hola, No es posible delimitarlo por posiciones de texto fijas. Por otra parte, editarlo no es posible, puesto que es una base muy grande y encontrar como reemplazar un tab no lo veo tan facil cuando esta delimitados por tab jaja